# how to build JSONobject request to use in HttpPost

Tags: java, json, rest, http-post

I here is an example that I need to build:

```
{
  "sendSmsRequest": {
  "to": "5511982694404",
  "msg": "funcionou"
  }
}
```

In order to do this, I have used JSONobject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("to", "123456789");
jsonObject.put("msg", "Mensagem Teste");
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
```

Here is the request:

```
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
post.setEntity(input);
```

But I dont know how put the "header" - "sendSmsRequest"...
There is any way to do This without using String??

```
String teste = "{\"sendSmsRequest\": { \"to\": \"123456789\",\"msg\": \"funcionou\"}}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("to", "123456789");
jsonObject.put("msg", "Mensagem Teste");
JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject1.put("sendSmsRequest", jsonObject);

StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonObject1.toString());
```

Like this you can have a `JSONObject` inside another `JSONObject`.

Comment: Thank you Moondaisy, that's exactly what I need!!